# Is there a way to create a sweeping arc in Android?

Tags: android, graphics, 2d, geometry

Currently I'm able to create a static arc

for example:

```
ShapeDrawable progressArc = new ShapeDrawable(new ArcShape(90, 12));
    progressArc.setIntrinsicHeight(100);
    progressArc.setIntrinsicWidth(100);
    progressArc.getPaint().setColor(Color.RED);
    ImageView iView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.background_circle);
    iView.setImageDrawable(progressArc);
```

where background_circle is the imageView inside which the arc is created. But when I try to give dynamic values to the second parameter of ArchShape by putting everything in a loop, it only renders the last instance. I also tried to sleep the thread but did not see any of the earlier instances being rendered.

```
int i=0;

    while(i<12)
    {
    ShapeDrawable progressArc = new ShapeDrawable(new ArcShape(90, i*12));
    progressArc.setIntrinsicHeight(100);
    progressArc.setIntrinsicWidth(100);
    progressArc.getPaint().setColor(Color.RED);
    ImageView iView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.background_circle);
    iView.setImageDrawable(progressArc);

    i++;
    }
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing this in a tight loop.  When you set the image drawable of the ImageView, a message is placed on the UI thread queue to redraw the ImageView.

However, because your loop does not give the UI thread enough time to process it's queue, the updates will happen some time after your loop finishes.  Thus, you will only see the last one.

Several ways to do this but the easiest is probably to draw your arc in a runnable and use a timer to draw each sweep, say every 10ms or whatever looks smooth.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps others:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(); 
        while(i<30)
        {
            i++;
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
            { 
                public void run() 
                {  

                    ShapeDrawable progressArc = new ShapeDrawable(new ArcShape(0, 12*i));
                    progressArc.setIntrinsicHeight(5);
                    progressArc.setIntrinsicWidth(5);
                    progressArc.getPaint().setColor(Color.BLUE);
                    iView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.background_circle);
                    iView.setImageDrawable(progressArc);

                    i++;
                }
            }, 1000*i);

        }
```

If anyone has a more efficient solution, please do let me know. :)